# How to modify Unique and ForeignKey for Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following code:

By default User model set username as Unique and Foreign Key, how to set email as unique and foreign key instead?

```py
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(),
        }
```

Best Regards,

Comment: `username` is not a foreignkey.

Comment: you can implement your own user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, thought there is a quicker way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally misunderstand the concept of Database,
here is the official documentation of [Django ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

1. Current workaround, first detect whether a user is exist in existing database, return error if duplicate
2. Set ForeignKey attribute from another model who wish to connect to User
   (3. Set Unique and ForeignKey in models.py not forms.py)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the case. 
You can use django-allauth and in the settings.py set

```
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = True
```

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html